# How to get page source in selenium2 python after page changed by JQuery

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am writing some test code in python using Selenium and getting a stale element error when I call driver.page_source. I understand the reason. I have navigated the page and the navigation inserts new page elements. But once these new elements are inserted in the page how can I get the source for the whole modified page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splinter: http://splinter.cobrateam.info/